# With DOMDocument, is it possible to filter the output of getElementsByTagName based on an additional parameter?

Tags: php, xml

Take the following example of this xml:

```
<xml>
<siblings>
    <brother>Derek</brother>
    <sister>Elaine</sister> 
    <sister>Flora</sister>
</siblings>
<siblings>
    <brother>Gary</brother>
    <sister>Hannah</sister> 
</siblings> 
</xml>
```

If I were to use the following code:

```
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("Family.xml");
$siblings = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('Siblings');
$sister = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('Sister');
```

This would normally return all instances of the tag "Sister", in this case "Elaine", "Flora" and "Hannah". Would it be possible to change it so that you could filter the tagnames by the name of one of the other nodes? For instance, using the name "Derek" to change the output to "Elaine" and "Flora" only.

Comment: you can use XPath for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath expressions allow you to use conditions to fetch nodes from a DOM.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<xml>
<siblings>
    <brother>Derek</brother>
    <sister>Elaine</sister> 
    <sister>Flora</sister>
</siblings>
<siblings>
    <brother>Gary</brother>
    <sister>Hannah</sister> 
</siblings> 
</xml>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$expression = '/xml/siblings[brother = "Derek"]/*[not(self::brother = "Derek")]';

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $sibling) {
  echo $sibling->textContent, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Elaine
Flora
```

### The Xpath Expression

- Fetch the `siblings` elements ...
  `/xml/siblings`
- ... if they have a child element `brother` with the value `Derek` ...
  `/xml/siblings[brother = "Derek"]`
- ... and fetch their child elements...
  `/xml/siblings[brother = "Derek"]/*`
- ... if they are not a `brother` element node with the value `Derek`.
  `/xml/siblings[brother = "Derek"]/*[not(self::brother = "Derek")]`

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful :)